# Oracle stored procedure - tracking validation errors

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I'm in the process of converting an MsSQL stored procedure into Oracle, but I've run into an issue that's making me question both implementations.

The Sql Server version creates a temp table inside the stored procedure to track validation errors on what can potentially be a somewhat large dataset (hundreds of thousands of records). Each validation query selects the invalid IDs into the temp table with an appropriate error message (specific to the query). Once all validation is done, the errors are inserted into a real table (which doesn't have a column to store the IDs). I can then easily insert the valid rows by filtering out the IDs from the temp error table.

I hope that makes sense. And just to reiterate, the reason I don't simply use the "real" error table is that it doesn't contain a column for me to store the IDs of the invalid rows (I can't change this).

I know that I can use a normal/global temporary table in Oracle, but the more I read into it, the more it sounds like this is bad practice. What's a good alternative to do this in Oracle? Collections?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of "validations" are that? To prevent errors when running a DML statement?

Comment: No, it's validating the data itself based on custom business rules.

Comment: So what is the "*can then easily insert the valid rows by filtering out*" part about?

Comment: It sounds like you're pulling a lot of data, then gradually excluding some of it afterwards; why not just filter in the first place, so you never see the rows that fail validation? That would probably be more efficient and simpler.

Comment: I used to just delete any invalid rows from the source table that was found to be invalid as I went along (because the source table is typically generated and populated at runtime from some other data source), but a requirement came up for users to be able supply their own source table to the SP. In this case, I can't delete the invalid data since the user might want to rectify the validation errors and try again.

Comment: I'd look at DML error logging (https://www.oratable.com/dml-error-logging/) That'll automatically write the errors to a log table.  If you really want to keep the existing error table as well, you could always copy the errors over.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just insert the errors into the real target table when the error occurs instead of into a #TEMP table then moving them later?  You did not list your Oracle version but you can create a global temporary table on the system then in your stored procedure a private to your session temporary table would be created on insert.  However, temp tables are normally not needed in Oracle.  The entire process design sounds suspect.  It is possible in Oracle to bulk insert the data capturing individual row errors from the bulk operation. If you or some members of you team have a decent understanding how Oracle works then this process seems like a candidate for refactoring (redesign).